# How to install Ubuntu terminal on macOS?

Tags: macos, terminal, unix

I am new to macOS, and I was using Ubuntu for more than a decade.

Now, I switched to macOS and I am wondering how to get Ubuntu terminal on macOS?

Does anyone here know how to convert macOS terminal into Ubuntu one?

Comment: Can you clarify: what would it mean to "convert the macOS terminal into Ubuntu one"?  What is it you are trying to achieve?  The default shell in macOS these days is zsh.  Are you saying you want to switch to bash or something?  Or maybe you want to look at homebrew, the mac package manager?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to switch to bash shell/

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://support.apple.com/guide/terminal/change-the-default-shell-trml113/2.13/mac/13.0

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't work. I am trying to execute the Ubuntu commands on macOS.

Comment: Which commands? Can you give some examples?

Comment: HTTPS_PROXY=http://localhost:3128 curl https://external.domain.com/

Comment: That is a potentially valid command no matter which shell you are using.  How does it fail?  It sounds like you’re trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: As you already got an answer to the question asked, please post a new question stating the actual problem you are running into (the command you try to run and how it fails).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When people think "terminal" there are (at least) three different things.

First, there's "virtual terminal emulator", a program that displays window on the screen and draws all those letters inside. In other words, it's responsible for how the "terminal" looks like. On Ubuntu it's (I guess) gnome-terminal, whereas on macOS it's Terminal.app. I doubt you can install gnome-terminal on macOS, but you can try different Terminal.app alternatives such as [iTerm2](https://iterm2.com), [kitty](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/), [alacritty](https://alacritty.org) or [Hyper](https://hyper.is).

Second, there's a "shell" - a program that interprets commands typed by the user and runs them. I.O.W. it's responsible for how the "terminal" behaves, it defines particular syntax for running commands. Both OSes come with assorted selection of shells and default to bash on Ubuntu and zsh on macOS, but bash is still (I believe) installed as an alternative. Running bash ad-hoc is possible by just typing `bash`. To change default shell permanently, you can use `chsh` command.

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

Or, by opening "Users & Groups" Preference pane, right-clicking on current user name, selecting "Advanced Options..." and selecting desired shell from  "Login shell" dropdown.

One is not limited to shells installed with the operating system, popular third party shells include [fish](https://fishshell.com) and [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-macos).

Third, there are actual commands and command-line utilities. Some are the same on both operating systems, eg. `curl`. Some are mostly the same but different "flavours", for example `ls` and `ps` behave slightly different on Ubuntu and macOS. Some, such as `wget` are missing on macOS but can't be installed using third-party tools. Some, like `apt`/`apt-get` are Ubuntu (Debian) specific but there exist tools that provide comparable functionality, such as [Homebrew](https://brew.sh).

Comment: The version of bash that comes in macOS is quite old (because of licensing conflicts) and missing some newer features, but you can install a more recent version with homebrew if you want.